# How can I assign a variable to HTML form elements using a PHP For() loop?

Tags: php, html

I am creating some HTML form elements using a PHP loop. I have a variable coming from a query that I am using to count how many elements I need. What I need to do is assign different variables to the form at each loop. Here is my code:
{

```
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $WMATTND; ++$x)
    {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<label>Please enter name for badge:</label>";
        echo "<input style='HEIGHT: 22px WIDTH: 427px' size='21' name='nameBadge'>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<label>";
        echo "Select Title for badge: ";
        echo "<select id='badgeTitle' name='badgeTitle'>";
        echo "<option>Select Badge Title</option>";
        echo "<option value='owner'>Owner</option>";
        echo "<option value='manager'>Manager</option>";
        echo "<option value='buyer'>Buyer</option>";
        echo "<option value='guest'>Guest</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</label>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo "<label>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='saturdayBk' id='saturdayBk'>";
        echo "Saturday Breakfast</label>";
        echo "</p>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo "<label>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='saturdayLh' id='saturdayLh'>";
        echo "Saturday Lunch</label>";
        echo "</p>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo "<label>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sundayBk' id='sundayBk'>";
        echo "Sunday Breakfast</label>";
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }

?>
```

}

An example I need would be to take 'nameBadge' and give it a variable of 'nameBadgex$' with x$ being the current loop number.

Comment: Just learning it sorry :)

Comment: If there is another way to do this, please let me know?

Comment: You only need one echo for the whole thing and use 2 "" at the beginning of the echo and at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this line

```
echo "<input style='HEIGHT: 22px WIDTH: 427px' size='21' name='nameBadge'>";
```

to :

```
echo "<input style='HEIGHT: 22px WIDTH: 427px' size='21' name='nameBadge".$x."'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to append the current value of the variable `$x` to the input name try this:

```
echo "<input style='HEIGHT: 22px WIDTH: 427px' size='21' name='nameBadge{$x}'>";
```

Please note if you need the value appended to the rest of your name values you would just add this after the value:

```
{$x}
```

So for example the select name would go from:

```
echo "<select id='badgeTitle' name='badgeTitle'>";
```

To:

```
echo "<select id='badgeTitle' name='badgeTitle{$x}'>";
```

Also you will need to do this to your id values since id values must be unique and on a person note I would change your code from using single quotes to using double quotes around HTML attribute values.